# MVC, difference between controller and model?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I was watching some Swift instructional videos from Stanford on youtube.  The instructor (Paul Hagerty, great teacher!) speaks about how iOS is built around the idea of MVC (model-view-controller).  I've read some people say on stack overflow that the idea is dead, and others say that a lot of web developers use this terminology now.

I'm having trouble differentiating between controller and model.  I've read MVC described as user interface (web page/UI), controller (server), and model (database).  But the instructor described it as view (UI, which is easy to understand), model (data and logic that does a calculation for example), and controller (which connects model and view with your specific programming logic).

What I don't understand is if there is no database in the case of a standalone application (not web), aren't we also creating the data and logic of how our program works at the same time?  What is the difference between controller and model in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is the data. Imagine a table view controller. The view is the table view. The controller is the UITableViewController. The model can be as simple as an array of strings.

The controller mediates between the model and the view. It picks the data that it wants to display and installs it in the view.

For a really simple view controller that just shows some text, the model could be as simple as a string. If the text is static, a view controller might not even have a true, separate model. It would just display the text that's baked into the storyboard.

Comment: So, the model is essentially the actual memory locations on a computer where something like an array (or any object/data) is stored?  Which is why this is similar to the database example I would guess.  Typing out and inserting what you put into the array is the controller, and the view is displaying that array data on the UI?

Comment: You would typical think in more abstract terms than memory location. A model is typically an object; it could be a simple string or array as mentioned here or a more complex object, that encapsulates a database and includes methods to operate on the model. For example, an "order" model object might have methods to add/remove line items from the order as well as submitting an order, marking it as paid, etc.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of being crucified for over-simplification: you can think of MVC as a way to separate "concerns" - in English - each has it's own "responsibility" (separation of concerns).

So in your "simple example" you could "separate" the concepts as a client and a server - risking even more shame, a `browser` and some web site.

1. `controller`: The browser takes user input and makes a request to;
2. `model`: A web site that responds with some data which could simply be a HTML document
3. `view`: The browser renders that data to user

So:

- The browser doesn't "know" how the data was created/built, it just manages the request/response and displays the result
- All the web site does is build some data and give it (back) to the requester. It doesn't care how it's used/rendered/displayed/filtered etc.
- All the view does is render/display data in some meaningful way to the user. It doesn't care where the data came from, nor how it was built.

Hth.